# Error message: type StudentList does not take parameters

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and test this LinkedList type but when I do I get an error message. My code for StudentList.java is as follows

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentList extends LinkedList
{
    private int newInt;
    private boolean newE;
    public StudentList(int i, boolean e) {
        newInt = i;
        newE = e;
}

public boolean offer(boolean e) {
       return e;
}


}
```

When I compile the file OfferDrive.java, which is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class OfferDriver
{
    public static void main ( String[] args)
    {
            StudentList<Integer> ilist = new StudentList<Integer>( );
            StudentList<String> slist = new StudentList<String>( );

            String s;
            Integer i;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter a word to offer (\"stop\" to stop):\t");
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                    s = in.next();
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) { break; }
                    slist.offer(s);
                    System.out.println("Size is: " + slist.size());
                    System.out.print("Please enter a word to offer(\"stop\"tostop):\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + slist);
            String si = slist.peek();
            System.out.println("Testing peek(): " + si);

            System.out.print("Please enter an integer to offer (<any word> to stop):\t");
            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    i = in.nextInt();
                    ilist.offer(i);
                    System.out.println("Size is: " + ilist.size());
                    System.out.print("Please enter an integer to offer (<any word> to stop):\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + ilist);
            int pi = ilist.peek();
            System.out.println("Testing peek(): " + pi);
    }

}
```

I get this error code

```
OfferDriver.java:16: error: type StudentList does not take parameters
                StudentList<Integer> ilist = new StudentList<Integer>( );
                       ^
OfferDriver.java:16: error: type StudentList does not take parameters
                StudentList<Integer> ilist = new StudentList<Integer>( );
                                                        ^
OfferDriver.java:17: error: type StudentList does not take parameters
                StudentList<String> slist = new StudentList<String>( );
                       ^
OfferDriver.java:17: error: type StudentList does not take parameters
                StudentList<String> slist = new StudentList<String>( );
                                                       ^
```

Please note StudentList.java is a work in progress and I mean to only test the method offer() at this point. Thanks for any and all help

Comment: compiler error is self explanatory. there is no type parameter for your StudentList class

Comment: What should I use as a type parameter then? <E>?

Comment: see answer below. why you have created separate StudentList class instead of using LinkedList directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your `StudentList` class like this if you want it to take type parameter

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentList<T> extends LinkedList<T>
{
private int newInt;
private boolean newE;

public StudentList(){
   super();
}
public StudentList(int i, boolean e) {
    newInt = i;
    newE = e;
}

public boolean offer(boolean e) {
   return e;
}


}
```

Comment: While this compiles, I get a new error message `OfferDriver.java:16: error: constructor StudentList in class StudentList<T> cannot be applied to given types;
                StudentList<Integer> ilist = new StudentList<Integer>( );
                                             ^
  required: int,boolean
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class StudentList`

Comment: you have to provide default constructor because you have provided one parameterized one. see updated answer

Comment: @GEARZ That is really not hard to understand. Have you even tried it? There is no constructor in the `StudentList` class that takes doesn't take any argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition is wrong.
Please attention to following class declaration:

```
public class StudentList<T> extends LinkedList <T>
```

Comment: If I do that Symbol T will not be found